# is .net framework required in install shield?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, frameworks

I have one question regarding activeX control.

We have developed an application in VC++. In that we have dialog as a container and we are hosting in it, the ActiveX control developed in C# and .net framework 3.5. I want to know that is it required to include .net framework 3.5 in the install build that we will create?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not related to Install Shield. If your application requires .NET Framework 3.5 to be installed, you need to install it by installer if it is not installed.

You can't guarantee it will be installed beforehand on end user's machine - this is the reason.